# In Julia, how to convert a unsigned number to a signed number like in C?

Tags: performance, optimization, type-conversion, julia

suppose i have a number `0x83`, if it is a unsigned, it will be 131, or if it is a signed number, it will be -125.
It is very easy in C that i can just write s8(0x83) to convert it to -125, cause the number is 0x83, it just explain the number.
but in Julia, it is different, the UInt8 type can not convert to Int8 easily, I should first judge if it in the Int8's range, and then convert it, otherwise i will use the Int16 type to help.
So, how can i do the convertion efficiently and in high performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
julia> reinterpret(Int8, 0x83)
-125
```

This is fast and non-allocating:

```
julia> @btime reinterpret(Int8, 0x83)
  1.200 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
-125
```

This works also on byte sequences, in this case most effort is to allocate the new vector:

```
julia> @btime reinterpret(Int8, [0x83, 0x84, 0x85, 0x86, 0x87, 0x88])
  21.206 ns (1 allocation: 64 bytes)
6-element reinterpret(Int8, ::Vector{UInt8}):
 -125
 -124
 -123
 -122
 -121
 -120
```